# Appium: Can I Automate a Webpage on Chrome for Android Browser?

Tags: android, robotframework, appium

I would like to use Appium to launch the Chrome browser on my Android device and find elements on a certain webpage.  Can this be done?  If so, how?

Thank you.

Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as platform is not specified I will answer using Windows, Visual Studio 2013 and .NET Framework 4.5.

**Environment:**

1. Install [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) or [Visual Studio 2015 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx). It is needed in order Appium could use android sdk tools to work with emulator or real devices.
2. Download [latest version of Appium](https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/). No need to install. It works right after unziping.
3. In Appium Settings:
   Check "Use Browser" option and choose Chrome.
   Check "SDK Path" option and set path.
4. [Update Chrome Driver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) (because it's not always a latest version in Appium pack).
   Relative path to chrome driver in appium pack \node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows
5. In order to run tests on your Adnroid device you should [activate USB debugging mode](http://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm) and connect it to the PC

**Coding:**

1. Create new Unit Test Project in Visual Studio 2013:
   File → New Project → Visual C# → Test → Unit Test Project
   By doing this you will use for your test framework MSTest.exe 
   There are several others if you want, [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) for example.
2. In Solution Explorer:
   Right Click on project name → Manage NuGet Packages → Serch Appium Web Driver → Add to project
   It's needed so you can you web driver.
3. In created project set [desired capabilities](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?csharp#appium-server-capabilities).
   I use following:

   ```
   public void InitializeDriver()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Appium server");
       _capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

       _capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Nexus One");
       _capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "300");
       _capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Chrome");
       _capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "5.0.1");
       _capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Android");

       //Application path and configurations
       _driver = new AndroidDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), _capabilities);
   }
   ```
4. In order to find elements on web pages you should use locators, e.g. unique object identifiers. How can you find those identifiers? I use Chrome Web Tools that allows emulate web site presentation on given mobile device. After view was emulated you can inspect elements you want. For example, let's assume I want to find search block on google.com:
   [image: Inspect element]

So code will loke like:
    var element = _driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='lst-ib']");

**Running Test:**

1. In order to run your tests Start Appium Server by pressing play button in the top right corner
2. Press F5 in Visual Studio

This it. Keep in mind that Appium and Android SDK are changing fast, so there could be some some updates to the Guide.

Comment: Really great tutorial! Do you know how to run Appium tests for embedded Android Browser (not Chrome)? I haven't got real device, work only on emulator and on emulator installing Chrome is probably impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

From their website:

> Yes (but not when using Selendroid backend).
>
> - Automation is effected using a bundled Chromedriver server as a proxy.
> - With 4.2 and 4.3, automation works on official Chrome browser or Chromium only.
> - With 4.4+, automation also works on the built-in “Browser” app.
> - Chrome/Chromium/Browser must already be installed on the device under test.

The first place you want to look for how to do this is the [Appium Documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#mobile-chrome-on-emulator-or-real-device) on ChromeDriver, Android, and webapps

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Once you set the correct DesiredCapabilites() and run AppiumDriver, you can follow it up like a normal desktop webpage automation using selenium.

I use these capabilities for my devices

```
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Chrome"); 
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Your device name here");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"4.4");
```

Cheers